# why UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is crashing on camera switch change?

Tags: camera, ios10, application-settings

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

its work fine for other settings like :

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard"]];
```

or wifi or general

Its crashing with **Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9** for only **UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString when switch state change ON/OFF**

else if we don't change switch state change ON/OFF then it debug properly, visit all the delegate methods.

Comment: I added the "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" key to my info.plist file and it works now.

Comment: Hello, have you ever able to fix this issue? If yes, please post your answer or comment me back with a solution.

Comment: Actually its not crash. it terminate app to adopt new settings. so its launch app again. You can take a tour of any app how they managed same issue. except WhatsApp.